# Why does G1 Old gen max memory in jmx equal to max heap size?

Tags: java, jvm, jmx, g1gc

I start a tomcat instance enabled with jmx, I check G1 old gen memory stat, find max memory = max heap size.

- The environment

```sh
# uname -a
Linux bogon 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 24 14:31:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

- jvm option

```sh
# ps -ef|grep tomcat
tomcat    3177     1  7 10:23 ?        00:00:06 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/apps/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1696m -Xmx1696m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8415 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8415 -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/apps/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/apps/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap -Dprocessname=tomcat start
```

- jmap result

```sh
# jmap -heap 3177
Attaching to process ID 3177, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.65-b01

using thread-local object allocation.
Garbage-First (G1) GC with 1 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 1778384896 (1696.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 1066401792 (1017.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 100663296 (96.0MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 1048576 (1.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 1696
   capacity = 1778384896 (1696.0MB)
   used     = 84934656 (81.0MB)
   free     = 1693450240 (1615.0MB)
   4.775943396226415% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 81
   capacity = 93323264 (89.0MB)
   used     = 84934656 (81.0MB)
   free     = 8388608 (8.0MB)
   91.01123595505618% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 0
   capacity = 0 (0.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   0.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 0
   capacity = 1685061632 (1607.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 1685061632 (1607.0MB)
   0.0% used

12869 interned Strings occupying 1777832 bytes.
```

- Question

The jmx item `java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=G1 Old Gen,Usage.max` is 1778384896, it equals to the max heap size.

If Old gen memory is not enough, all heap memory will be used for Old gen memory?

Comment: The maximum only tells you the limit. It doesn't imply that you will be able to allocate that much memory. If no specific limit for the Old Gen exist, the heap limit is the obvious limit for it.

Comment: @Holger one more question, what does the commit value mean in JMX?

Answer (score 2):

I really faced the same issue, that the max memory of old gen is as the same as the value of `-Xmx`, while the max memory of eden and survivor are both -1 (unlimited) in JMX interface. Just 5 months after your question, there was an issue ticket for openjdk "[Revamp G1 JMX MemoryPool and GarbageCollector MXBean definitions](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196991)". I'm afraid we can only be waiting for it being resolved.